# Adding key value beginning of an array

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a key->value pair beginning of the a javascript JSON array like so :

```
var temp = new Array();
temp = {
          ['LABEL_ID': 10, 'LABEL_TYPE': A3],
          ['LABEL_ID': 17, 'LABEL_TYPE': A6]
       }
```

what I want to do :

```
var temp = new Array();
temp = {
          'PAPER': A80 
               ['LABEL_ID': 10, 'LABEL_TYPE': A3],
               ['LABEL_ID': 17, 'LABEL_TYPE': A6]
       }
```

could you please help me?

**EDIT**
here is the my code:

```
// returns paper type from selected grid line
var ppt     = Ext.getCmp('labelType').getValue();

// returns selected grid rows
var rows    = Ext.getCmp('labelGrids').getSelectionModel().getSelection();


// here is my array that I want to add ppt variable value to existing array, then I will convert this to a JSON array
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
   prints[i] = {'LABEL_ID': rows[i].data.LABEL_ID, 'LABEL_TYPE':rows[i].data.LABEL_TYPE}
}
```

The reason is to adding `ppt` value beginning of the array just I need ones this record in server side. Therefore, I don't want to repeat in all lines!

Comment: JSON arrays stores same type of objects. You may give your previous array a key like 'MyArray' and restructure your object.

Comment: You are assigning an Object to temp

Comment: dear friend, A80 value comes from another variable which users selecting a combo box. So the problem raising in there. How can I add this value beginning of an array?

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect you are declaring an array then overwriting it with an object that is invalid.

Comment: 1st point. {} denotes object and [] denotes array, so there is no array here. May be its a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I hope you meant this script in your question:

And to answer your edited question, A simple way is to wrap it in another object:

```
var temp = new Array();
temp = [
  {"LABEL_ID": 10, "LABEL_TYPE": "A3"},
  {"LABEL_ID": 17, "LABEL_TYPE": "A6"}
       ]
 // wrap temp in another object;

 var obj = {};
 obj.PAPER = A80;
 obj.Data = temp;
 //And convert to json.
 console.log(JSON.stingify(obj));
```

Output:

```
{"PAPER":"A80","Data":[{"LABEL_ID":10,"LABEL_TYPE":"A3"},{"LABEL_ID":17,"LABEL_TYPE":"A6"}]}
```

Hope this helps. Calling the function will add the required proptery to your objects

```
var temp = new Array();
temp = [
  {"LABEL_ID": 10, "LABEL_TYPE": "A3"},
  {"LABEL_ID": 17, "LABEL_TYPE": "A6"}
       ]

  addPaperProperty(temp, 'PAPER', ['AA','BB']);

  function addPaperProperty(currentArray, newPropertyField, newPropertyArr){
    var newArray = [];
    var i=0;
    $(temp).each(function(){
       this[newPropertyField] = newPropertyArr[i++];
      newArray.push(this);
    });
    console.log(newArray);
    return newArray;
  }
```

And the result will be

```
[{LABEL_ID: 10, LABEL_TYPE: "A3", PAPER: "AA"},
{LABEL_ID: 17, LABEL_TYPE: "A6", PAPER: "BB"}]
```

Comment: Akhil, could you please check edited question? I don't want to add `PAPER` value in whole records which I need only ones in server side.

Answer (score 2):

If you're so inclined I would say this is the way to go for you.

You're javascript syntax is invalid as it is.
You want to add "label"-objects to your Array and furthermore youre assigning `temp` to a new object overwriting the Array you just created.

If you wanna add to the array you have to use the method `.push()`

Like this:

```
labelArray.push({'LABEL_ID': '10', 'LABEL_TYPE': 'A3'});
labelArray.push({'LABEL_ID': '17', 'LABEL_TYPE': 'A6'});
```

Otherwise this might the a pointer in the right direction

```
var labelArray = new Array({'LABEL_ID': 10, 'LABEL_TYPE': A3},
               {'LABEL_ID': 17, 'LABEL_TYPE': A6});
var paper = {

    papertype : A80,
    labels : labelArray

}
```

But its neither good nor is it clean but it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** an array. The type of such a variable is known as hashtable as it defines key/value pairs.

Some important points before the actual answer:

- Both key and value can be of any type, but good practice is to have the keys as plain strings.
- The value can be anything, including plain arrays and even another hashtable.
- You can't have just a key without a value.

So, to make your code valid you can have such a thing:

```
temp = {
    'PAPER': 'A80', 
    'LABELS': [{'LABEL_ID': 10, 'LABEL_TYPE': 'A3'}, 
               {'LABEL_ID': 17, 'LABEL_TYPE': 'A6'}]
};
```

This will add ordinary key/value pair then a key with the value being array of hashtables.

To access specific label you can have such code:

```
var id = temp["LABELS"][1]["LABEL_ID"];
```

Keep in mind that JavaScript is case sensitive so case is important in the key names, meaning `temp["paper"]` will return *undefined*.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/TuJbH/).

Comment: What is `ppt`? What it contains?

Comment: `ppt` is PAPER that I want to add array.

Answer (score 1):

Your objects appear to be invalid all over the place:
The outer brackets should be square: `[ ]`, if you really want it to be an array, and the inner ones curly `{ }`, since those are objects.

Also, unless `A3` and `A6` are varialbes you've defined before, you'll need to enclose them in apostrophes, since they're strings:

```
var temp = [
    {'LABEL_ID': 10, 'LABEL_TYPE': 'A3'},
    {'LABEL_ID': 17, 'LABEL_TYPE': 'A6'}
]
```

Now, if you want that added property in your array, you're probably best off doing it like this:

```
var temp = [
    {'PAPER': 'A80'},
    {'LABEL_ID': 10, 'LABEL_TYPE': 'A3'},
    {'LABEL_ID': 17, 'LABEL_TYPE': 'A6'}
]
```

Or, make `temp` a object, instead:

```
var temp = {
    'PAPER':'A80',
    'labels':[
        {'LABEL_ID': 10, 'LABEL_TYPE': 'A3'},
        {'LABEL_ID': 17, 'LABEL_TYPE': 'A6'}
    ]
}
```

(In objects, you always have a `key:value` relation, in arrays, you never have that.

Comment: The `new Array()` line isn't really necessary.

Comment: @Zeta: You're right, copy-pasted it without paying too much attention.

Answer (score -1):

Hi this is a valid JSON Object

```
temp = {
      'PAPER': A80, 'LIST' : {
           ['LABEL_ID': 10, 'LABEL_TYPE': A3],
           ['LABEL_ID': 17, 'LABEL_TYPE': A6]
       }
   }
```

Comment: No, it's not. You must have key/value.

Comment: the Value of 'List' is a new Object and a Value!

Comment: No it's not. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TuJbH/2/), Chrome console clearly says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [".

Comment: yeah i saw it a few mins ago :( sorry :) to fast